# Number of limit points of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

$x_n$ be a real sequence converging to $x$. What is the maximum number of limit points of the sequence $y_n=\lfloor {x_n^2} \rfloor+\lfloor {x_n} \rfloor$?

Answer (score 1):

I attempted this question on the basis of where the values of $x_n$ lie.

Case 1) If $x_n$ is a integer sequence then it is eventually constant and so is the sequence $y_n$.

Case 2) If $x_n$ is not an integer sequence then we take two cases- $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$. In the later case there will be nbds $B(x,\epsilon_1)$ and $B(x^2,\epsilon_2)$ such that $B(x,\epsilon_1) \subset [k,k+1]$ and $B(x^2,\epsilon_2)\subset[m,m+1]$, i.e., after finite number of terms the sequences $x_n$ and $x_n^2$ will be properly contained in the closed interval with integer boundary points. Hence, $y_n\to k+m$ as $n\to \infty$. In the former case there can be further two cases, $x_n$ convrging to $x$ from one side or it converges as an alternating sequence. In these cases proceeding similarly we get number of possible limit points of the sequence $y_n$ equal to 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: I believe this proof is ultimately good but would benefit from a bit more rigor. (a) It could be that $x_n^2$ converges to an integer even if $x_n$ doesn't, (b) "alternating sequence" normally means "$x_n-x$ keeps changing sign all the time" - which is not what it means here, (c) "proceeding similarly" - quite vague. I think you will find that there will be three separate cases to analyze: $x<0, x=0, x>0$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Also, by using alternating I exactly meant the change of sign. Because $x$ being an integer, terms to its right and left will have different floor values.

Comment: My point was: either you imply the sign of $x_n-x$ and $x_n^2-x^2$ changes every time $n$ is incremented (in which case it can be argued that not all sequences are covered in the proof!) or it doesn't, but still changes sign infinitely many times (which then IMHO needs clarification).

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you again. I will work on this proof.